# Tableau - Monthly Date to Quarterly affecting Calculations

Tags: tableau-api

I'm creating a basic line graph with the following data:

```
Jan 2015    $1
Feb 2015    $2 
Mar 2015    $3
```

My monthly data is all inclusive of prior months, so it basically represents everything that has happened in the past as well as the current month results.

In Tableau, when I set the dates to Quarterly it shows up as Q1 2015 ($1 + $2 + $3) where as I just want $3 (March 2015).

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right now, on the rows (I assume) shelf, you have SUM(whatever your field is). Click the drop-down on that pill and change the calculation instead to Maximum. It would then be MAX(whatever your field is).

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the rows doesn't say SUM but rather AGG. I'm not sure how to proceed...am I able to filter out only Quarterly Dates?

Perhaps, I can just show March 2015 and relabel as Q1 2015?

Comment: Herein lies the problem with not enough detail/screenshots/linked workbooks in your question--we have to assume what you're doing. Did you make a calculated field that is SUM(whatever your field is called)?  Sounds like it if the row says AGG. If so change that calculated field to MAX. If not, share a workbook or a screenshot.